# Trying to select a <ul> that follows a <h2> which must contain a <a href="with a specific URL">

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm working on a DocBook export to HTML and have little options to add "smart" classes to the HTML.

I'm left with a structure that looks like:

```
<h2><a href="the url I'm using to identify the UL set that follows">...</a></h2>
<ul>
...
</ul>
```

There are no classes on the <h2>, none on the <ul> either.

So my idea would be:

select the UL that comes after a H2 that contains an A with the HREF attribute to "my URL".

a combination of

```
h2 ~ ul
```

was what I first had in mind, but I can't figure out how to specify H2 with the "contains an A with the HREF attribute I want"...

Comment: U can't use a sibling selector with child elements

Comment: If your only recourse is CSS then you'll need to use either ancestor tags or *"older siblings"* as in tags that precede the `h2` and `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `has` selector to check whether the `h2` have anchor tag and then target the immediate next `ul` selector.

```css
h2:has(a[href='www.test.com']) + ul {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<h2><a href="www.test.com">test</a></h2>
<ul>
Change to Green
</ul>
<h2><a href="www.testing.com">testing</a></h2>
<ul>
Not to Change Green
</ul>
```

Comment: You should include the caveat that Firefox doesn't support [`:has()`](https://caniuse.com/?search=has)